# HTTP call on screen load in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

We have a Features class that we are trying to fill when a screen loads. Its an http call that returns the object. Im struggling with how to do this. All of our http calls are done on a button click:

here is the call

```
      Future<Features> getFeatureStatus(String userID) async {

      Features _features;

     final response =
     await http.post('http://url/api/Features',
     headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
  body: json.encode({'userID' : userID }));

 _features = Features.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

   return _features;


  }
```

When i try to call it at the top of the class I get errors and cant get to the values.

```
class FlutterReduxApp extends StatelessWidget {
static final User user;
static final Features features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId);
```

The error I get is --  "A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Features'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Features'.dart(invalid_assignment)"

Im sure im doing something incorrect here but I havent done a screen load call yet.

Comment: the method returns ```Future<Features>```, not ```Features```. Also this code should be inside a ```StatefullWidget``` and when the http is done you set the features with ```setState```.

Comment: Ok, where do I place the call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getFeatureStatus` function is returning a `Future<Features>` while you're trying to read it as type `Features` in the stateless widget.

There are different ways to read the value but since you have a button, you could convert the widget into a `StatefulWidget` then use the `onPressed` function to read the value and update the state afterwards such as.

```
onPressed: () async {
  features = await getFeatureStatus(user.userId);

  setState((){
  // do something
  });
}
```

In this case, the value `features` cannot be a static final so you'll have to change it to `Features features`.

Edit based on comment:

You could also do this inside an initState:

```
Features features;
@override
void initState () {
 super.initState();
 _asyncMethod();
}

_asyncMethod() async {
 features = await getFeatureStatus(user.userId);
 setState((){});
}
```

so in the widget build method you could do:

```
return (features == null) 
       ? CircularProgressIndicator()
       : MyWidget(...); // where features is used.
```

Comment: Thanks. Im not using a button Im doing this when the screen loads

Comment: Oh then I just misunderstood this part "All of our http calls are done on a button click"..

Comment: No problem sorry for the confusion. I havent done a call when the screen loads yet.

Comment: I tried this:  Features features;
@override
void initState () {
 super.initState();
 features = getFeatureStatus(user.userID);
}

Comment: and i get this error: A value of type 'Future<Features>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Features'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Features'.dart(invalid_assignment)

Comment: When I debug this the http call never gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 getFeatureStatus(user.userId).than((features)
{
// you will get the features object
//you can work on that object
}
);
```

calling the getFeaturesStatus method in the initState() when using the statefull.

Comment: so would the call look like this?  static final Features features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId);

Comment: you can use the await before the getfeatureStatus with an async

Comment: you can create a method that will be called in the initState(). So now its on you how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, this line `static final Features features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId);` will not work as you are trying to assign a type Future to the type Features.

The solution for this is to `await` the future so that it resolves and returns a Feature data type that satisfies your variable named 'features'.

This goes as follows: `static final Features features = await getFeatureStatus(user.userId);` but this has to be in a separate function which is explicitly defined with the async parameter.

This solves the error in the respect of code that you have written, but as you stated that you want this to load after the screen loads (Or technically, when the main widget is "mounted").

The solution for this logical aspect can be the use of `this.mounted`.

All widgets have a bool this.mounted property. It turns true when the buildContext is assigned.

In short, suppose you want to run a function after any widget is mounted/loaded, you can test it via

`if(this.mounted){
 //Whatever you want to do when the widget has been mounted...
 }`